# Combinatorics and Probability- where am I wrong?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let there be a cube with $n$ sides denoted $1,...,n$ each. The cube is tossed $n+1$ times. For $1\le k\le n$, what is the probability that exactly $k$ first tosses give different number (i.e, the $(k+1)$-st toss give a number that was already gotten.) I really need to know why I got a slightly different answer from the official one.

My attempt: Let us build a uniform sample space. $\Omega=\{a_i=(i_1,...,i_k)|1\le i_j\le n\}$. $|\Omega|=(n+1)^n$, $\forall \omega\in \Omega, P(\omega)={1\over |\Omega|}$.
We seek for the event $A=\{(i_1,...,i_k,i_{k+1},...,i_{n+1})|i_t\ne i_s, \forall 1\le t\ne s\le k, k\in \{i_1,...,i_k\}\}$.

**This is the problematic part:** $|A|={n\choose k}\cdot k!\cdot k \cdot n^{n-k-1} $. (Then I and the answer use the formula for probability of an even it a uniform sample space.)

**The point is, the answer says:** $|A|={n\choose k}\cdot k!\cdot k \cdot n^{n-k} $. I don't understand why; First I pick $k$ numbers, count all their permutations, then pick one of them for the $(k+1)$-th toss, and then I have $n-k-1$ tosses left, each of which has $n$ possibilities. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. My lacking familiarity with English wouldn't let me observe that I should use "st" instead of "th", which I should.

Comment: Isn't the cube tossed $n+1$ times? After toss $k+1$, you have $n-k$ tosses remaining. (Also, $\Omega=\{(i_1,\ldots,i_{n+1})|1\le i_j\le n\}$ so $|\Omega|=n^{n+1}$)

Comment: Oh, I overlooked it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As pointed out by grand_chat in a comment, the discrepancy is resolved by noting that the cube is cossed $n+1$ times, not $n$ times.